# Setting margin in XAML for dynamically created WPF controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic-controls, thickness

I have a WPF that creates buttons dynamically when the form is loaded and adds them to a StackPanel that has been declared in XAML.  I would like to define the style for these buttons completely in XAML inside the StackPanel.Resources.  So far I am able to do this for Style properties just fine, but what I am having trouble figuring out is the best way to do the margin.  I know that Margin is a Thickness and cannot actually be applied in a style, but must be defined as a static resource and applied directly to the Margin property.  Is there a way I can do this in XAML without resorting to the code-behind?

Here is the XAML for my StackPanel:

```
        <StackPanel
            x:Name="_dialogButtons"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right">

            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style
                    TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter
                        Property="MinWidth"
                        Value="75" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Padding"
                        Value="3" />
                </Style>                    
            </StackPanel.Resources>

        </StackPanel>
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: *"I know that Margin is a Thickness and cannot actually be applied in a style"* That's just not true.

Comment: Yeesh, I was WAY off on that one.  I'm not sure what I was thinking, I may have just been confused with a different issue I ran into in the past with a particular property that did not function the same way in styles that other properties did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state that *"I know that Margin is a Thickness and cannot actually be applied in a style"*, this is not correct. Margins can be applied in XAML, the `Thickness` type has a type converter that can convert a string to a `Thickness` allowing you to define it as follows:

```
<setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter
            Property="MinWidth"
            Value="75" />
        <Setter
            Property="Padding"
            Value="3" />
        <Setter
            Property="Margin"
            Value="3" />
    </Style>                    
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Padding` is a `Thickness` as well, and it seems you could add that just fine ;).

So just do it the same way as `Padding`.